# asp.net mvc load image src converty path

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to load image file from physical path with out create virtual directory?
I use C# code behaind and image  source is physical path?
How tio convert 
 C:\Folder\imageName.jpg 
to 
file:///C:/Folder/imageName.jpg

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use a controller action to serve that image:

```
public ActionResult MyImage()
{
    return File(@"C:\Folder\imageName.jpg", "image/jpg");
}
```

and in your view invoke this controller action to show the image:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("MyImage", "SomeController")" alt="myimage" />
```

The reason for this is because client browsers cannot access arbitrary files located on the server. If this image is not inside the virtual directory it cannot be referenced by a client. So it is the server that needs to expose it.